# Windows 7 RDP Problem - connecting to external zone with computer names

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, ip

I recently installed Windows 7, all is well so far, apart from using RDP to access computers outside my domain.

We use a datacenter, outside of our domain.

I was using Windows Vista before (not sure if this is relevant) - 
I could RDP no problem to the machines (using their machine names - Web10 for example)

I have changed my IP address to be the same as it was when i was using vista

We use a draytek firewall - we use DMZ Host to map my IP to an external ip- which is allowed to access the datacenter

I've disabled windows firewall

When i try to connect in Remote Desktop client, using Web10, I can't connect, however, if I enter the actual IP address, i can.

I have run out of ideas... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd need the fully qualified name, like web10.inside.externalhost.net or whatever to get to it... or those ip addresses mapped in your name resolution service, like in your local DNS servers or as Jessica stated locally in your machine's hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a name resolution issue on your new PC (and is not specific to any particular version of Windows).  Check your old PC to see if there were any hard-coded entries in your **`hosts`** file (which can be found at **`%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`** ª).  Copy any entries that you need from that file to your new system in the same file path.

Each entry needs to be in the form:

```
123.45.67.89    WebServerName
```

ª Some things to note:

1. The `hosts` file does not have a file extension... if you see a file named `hosts.sam`, that is *not* the one you are looking for (it is a sample file).
2. You can safely open and modify the file using Notepad.
3. The **`127.0.0.1 localhost`** entry must be present in the `hosts` file if the file exists.
4. Any text found on any line *after* a hash/pound sign (**`#`**) are comments and are not processed.

I hope this helps.